# file_exists not behaving properly

Tags: php, file, upload

I am writing a script to upload a file as part of my php project. If a file already exists with that same name, instead of moving the file anyway and overwriting whatever is there, I am using header() to refresh the page and add a message to rename the file before uploading.

However, it is not working. The program moves the file over regardless if the name is already taken.
I have tested 
`if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']))` and it seems to work independently but not within the structure of my program. I can't figure out where it goes wrong though.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include ('includes/openfile.php');

if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']))
{

$allowed = array('image/JPG', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'text/plain');

// validate the file type
if(in_array($_FILES['uploadFile']['type'], $allowed))
{

    //check if file exists with current file name in order to prevent overwrite -- prevents overwrite .htaccess attack as well as protecting user files
     if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']))
    {
            // file must have a unique name
            header("Location: file-upload.php?msg=" . urlencode(base64_encode("Please rename this file.")));

    }
    else
    {
            // file has unique name, so move it to uploads directory
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], "../uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
    }
}
else
{
            header("Location: file-upload.php?msg=" . urlencode(base64_encode("Please upload a .JPG, .jpeg, .png, or .txt file type")));    
}

// check for a file error
if($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] > 0)
{
 echo "<h1 class='jumbotron error'>There was an error because </h1>";

switch ($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'])
{
    case 1:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>File exceeds upload max file size</h2>";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>File exeeds max file size in html form</h2>";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>File was only partially uploadeded</h2>";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>No file was uploaded</h2>";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>No temporary folder was available</h2>";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>Unable to write to the disk</h2>";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>File upload stopped</h2>";
        break;


    default:
        echo "<h2 class='jumbtron'>A system error has occured</h2>";
        break;
    }
} 
else
{


# TODO: encrypt uploaded file

// delete tmp file
if(file_exists($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']))
{
    unlink($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']);
}

// let the user know the file was succesfully uploaded
header("Location: file-upload.php?success=" . urlencode(base64_encode("File uploaded successfully!")));

}
}


include ('includes/closefile.php');
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you 100% sure `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/"` and `"../uploads/"` both point to the same directory? Also, you should `exit;` after a header redirect to prevent more PHP from executing.

Comment: are you sure that the relative path ../uploads/ directory you move is same as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" directory?

Comment: Yes, I just checked and both paths are the same.

Comment: @DaveChen oops! I made sure to do that in all my other files except this one... Thanks!